How to send reply/output via a different python websocket after receiving input through another
I need to be able to send out some json through a different handler/socket after receiving a specific string through a  handler/socket, does anyone have any suggestions on how to achieve this? I also need to number the outputs of each item sent out, using a counting variable, should this be done using global variables or an incrementing counter inside each handler?
async def Hander1:
    test_data = load_json_test_file(“blah.json”)
    # send out initial json on connection
    await websocket.send(json.dumps(test_data))
    # send out different json when receive keyword through websocket3
    

async def Handler2:
    test_data = load_json_test_file(“blah2.json”)
    await websocket.send(json.dumps(test_data))

async def Handler3:
    test_data = load_json_test_file(“blah3.json”)
    await websocket.send(json.dumps(test_data))
    async for message in websocket:
    print(f"20784 Received {message} and {path}”)
    If message == “WORD”:
    # Send specific JSON output out via Handler1

async def main():
    
    server1 = await serve(Handler1, "localhost", 20780)
    server2 = await serve(Handler2, "localhost", 20781)
    server3 = await serve(Handler3, "localhost", 20782)
    print("launching websockets")
    await server1.serve_forever()
    await server2.serve_forever()
    await server3.serve_forever()

